# Customise the Processing Icon using java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I want to show the Processing Icon on the button once it is clicked to make understand the user that application is loading the page, he has to wait until it is completed.

Following is the Wait Cursor I got for the below code:

[image]

The code I developed to meet my above requirement is as follows:

```
 public static boolean waitCursorIsShowing;
 public Cursor waitCursor, defaultCursor;

 waitCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);
 defaultCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);

 waitCursorIsShowing = true;
 if (waitCursorIsShowing)
        {          
            JFrame frame.setCursor(waitCursor);

            -----------------------------------------------
            /* code to load the page/ perform the business logic */
            -----------------------------------------------

            waitCursorIsShowing = false;
            frame.setCursor(defaultCursor);
        }
```

This code is working well according to my requirement. But when I want to show the other Processing Image Icon on the button when it is clicked, the result I am getting is in reverse order. I mean when the button is clicked and page is loading, no Processing Image Icon is shown on the button, but when action is performed and button is released after Page load, then the application is showing the Processing Image Icon on the button.

Following is the Processing Image Icon I am getting for the below code:

[image]

Please help me where I am coding incorrect. Following is the modified code.

```
public static boolean waitCursorIsShowing;
 public Cursor waitCursor, defaultCursor;

 waitCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);
 defaultCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);

 waitCursorIsShowing = true;
 if (waitCursorIsShowing)
        {          

            URL url = getClass().getResource("/Images/loader8.gif");
            b4.setText("Loading");
            b4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(url));

            -----------------------------------------------
            /* code to load the page/ perform the business logic */
            -----------------------------------------------

            waitCursorIsShowing = false;
            b4.setIcon(new ImageIcon());
                b4.setText("Submit");
        }
```

b4 is the button on which I want to get the Processing Image Icon.

How to modify my code to customize the Icon on the button when it is clicked and application is loading the Page?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that events are all processed on the event dispatch thread, which is the same thread that handles painting. If you do your page loading on that thread, then the frame will not be able to repaint until the loading is complete. Instead, do the loading on a background thread, and use a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` call to set the icon back when you are done.

Comment: I didn't use any threads here, I used the Boolean values and the methods on frame like frame.setCursor(waitCursor), 
frame.setCursor(defaultCursor), can you please suggest me the code based on above code development?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper As Russsell stated - the above approach is broken and should not be used. It contradicts the swing event model and will thus not lead to the desired results.

Comment: You might also like to mention the [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class which has methods `process` and `done` which will be invoked on the EDT automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SwingWorker`:

```
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
    final JButton button = new JButton("Please, press me!");
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    frame.getContentPane().add(pane);

    final Cursor defaultCursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
    final Cursor busyCursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);
    final ImageIcon loadingIcon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Images/loader8.gif")));

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button.setIcon(loadingIcon);
            frame.setCursor(busyCursor);

            SwingWorker<String, Object> worker = new SwingWorker<String, Object>() {
                @Override
                public String doInBackground() throws InterruptedException {
                    // do some work...
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                        sb.append((char)(i + 65));
                        Thread.sleep(25);
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    try {
                        //set result of doInBackground work
                        pane.setText(get());
                        frame.setCursor(defaultCursor);
                        button.setIcon(null);

                    } catch (Exception ignore) {
                    }
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        }
    });

    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```